# Get position as int from Set<>.index in Swift

Tags: swift, set

I have a set collection and I want to get index of an element. I'm using `firstIndex` function of set but It returns `Set.index`. How can I convert it to int?

```
let index = mySet.firstIndex(of: dataSource) // This returns Set<>.index
```

[Set.index Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/index)

Comment: `Set` is unordered by definition, why are you trying to get an index from it?

Comment: I'm populating an UITableView with this set

Comment: As I've said, `Set` is unordered by definition - you should convert it to an `Array` and sort the array before displaying to guarantee correct results.

Comment: You need to use ordered Data structure for this - Array is great for this

Comment: `mySet.distance(from: mySet.startIndex, to: index)` as others have already mentioned the order of your set is unpredictable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set is unordered, try using an Array for example

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to convert a set index to an int

```
index.hashValue
```

however you will find that that index isn't very useful

```
Set(["a", "b", "c"]).firstIndex(of: "a")?.hashValue
// 5346078814578125500
```

this is because a set uses a hash table as its underlying storage mechanism. You'll see this if you try to print the index itself

```
Index(_variant: Swift.Set<Swift.String>.Index._Variant.native(Swift._HashTable.Index(bucket: Swift._HashTable.Bucket(offset: 3), age: -233657665)))
```

What `firstIndex` returns to you is simply the hashkey at which that element is stored. It does not relate to any kind of "position" because hash tables don't have a meaningful sense of position.